# C'est/Il est + superlative

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, pronoms

I have looked at the questions asked about this topic but I haven't found any that directly answers this question, unless I have missed it.

I would like to translate: "David? He is the most intelligent in our class."

I know the rule says:
- c'est + determiner (def. article, indef. article, demonstrative adj. etc.)
- il/elle est + adjective (unless we are describing someone/something in general: "un professeur, c'est intelligent)

I have a problem in applying this rule with the superlative, because a) there is a determiner, so I would be tempted to say "c'est" but b) the article is only there because of the structure of the superlative, this is essentially an adjective to a superlative degree - I see the article being a whole with the adjective", if that makes sense? So j'hésite entre les deux formes.

Which one do you think is correct?

```
  a) David? C'est le plus intelligent de la classe  

  b) David? Il est le plus intelligent de la classe  

  c) both
```

Any clarifications on the **reasons** why one or the other is correct would also be appreciated. I would also welcome any notes of the use/register of both if they both happened to be acceptable.

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more idiomatic way to say it is :

> *David ? **C'est** le plus intelligent de la classe.*

The alternative "***il est*** le plus..." is nevertheless sometimes used and definitely understood but sounds slightly odd or too literary and is more often heard from non-native speakers.

Note that only ***il*** is possible in a comparative context like this one:

> *Il est plus intelligent que les autres élèves de sa classe.*

Comment: Thank you Jilliagre- so it sounds like "le" is considered like a proper determiner here, and not as part of the adjective in the superlative degree. Which is further validated by your final example with a comparative, where the absence of a determiner forces us to use il/elle, as per rule.

Comment: I would say *le* is part of the superlative but keeps its definite determiner role. Instead of "idiomatic", I might have written "mainstream". *Il est le plus intelligent de la classe* is rarer but no rule forbids to use it.